# Xcode проблема с локализацией

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, локализация

Всем привет. Изучаю разработку под ios недавно из-за этого прошу строго не судить. Работаю над локализацией приложение. Но проблема в том что когда я перехожу настройки проекта в вкладку "Info" и пытаюсь добавить русскую локализацию мне предлагает добавить локализацию 2 Storyboard (из 7 Storyboard файлов) файлам. Эти два Storyboard по умолчание созданные (Main.storyboard , Launcher.storyboard). Storyboard которые создал я в процессе разработки он не учитывает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встаньте на сториборд и справа в File Inspector щелкните по Localize. После этого сториборд будет в списке на локализацию вместе с Main и LaunchScreen

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]